# How to replace a function pointer with a template parameter or a std::function?

Tags: c++, sonarlint

I run a sonarlint plugin in visualstudio.
I get a major problem about my code as below :

```
_declspec(dllexport) void GetInformation(void (add)(const char* pCarName))
{
    add("N3-988");
    add("N3-40");
    add("N3-41");
    add("N3-428");
}
```

The error is

```
cpp:S5205 : Replace this function pointer with a template parameter or a "std::function".
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: The warning seems bogus, just suppress it. `#pragma warning(suppress: S5205)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a real error, in a sense that you cannot use function pointer as a parameter. You can. Use of function pointers is discouraged for obscurity, flexibility and performance reasons. See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-5205 . So you may want to suppress it, if you are not concerned with these considerations.

Lack of flexibility means you cannot pass extra context (unless using so called "thunks"). This lack of flexibility can be addressed by using extra `void*` parameter for user context:

```
_declspec(dllexport) void GetInformation(
   void (add)(const char* pCarName, void* context), void* context)
{
    add("N3-988", context);
    add("N3-40",  context);
    add("N3-41",  context);
    add("N3-428", context);
}
```

You can also used `std::function`, as suggested, if you don't ming that your DLL will have C++ interface (so will depend on C++ runtime):

```
_declspec(dllexport) void GetInformation(std::function<void (const char*)> add)
{
    add("N3-988");
    add("N3-40");
    add("N3-41");
    add("N3-428");
}
```

Note that you cannot use `template` as suggested, since templates cannot be exported from DLL with `__declspec(dllexport)`. Template would have fixed performance due to avoiding indirections, but DLL interface means you can't avoid it.

---

Note that function as a parameter:

```
void GetInformation(void (add)(const char* pCarName))
```

equivalent to function pointer parameter due to so called *decay*:

```
void GetInformation(void (*add)(const char* pCarName))
```

The answer that suggest to replace one with the other is misleading, it wouldn't fix anything.

Answer (score 3):

The error is a red herring. You've mistyped the function pointer syntax, that's all. You need

```
void (*add)(const char* pCarName)
```

as the parameter type. `add` is then a function pointer, and its use in the function body (`add("N3-988");` etc.) is appropriate.

Comment: maybe clarify more explicitly that `void (add)(const char* pCarName)` is the type of a function which cannot be passed around directly

Comment: *"Replace this function pointer with a template parameter or a "std::function"."* You did none of the *"suggestions"*.

Comment: @Jarod42: Exactly. That's the beauty of compiler diagnostics. It's a bit like my telling my daughter "Don't think of elephants", then asking her what she's thinking about.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: Not unless you resort to template tricky, which might blow up `_declspec(dllexport)`. The latter was the hidden consideration in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like the following

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename FuncT>
void GetInformation(FuncT func)
{
    func("N3-988");
    func("N3-40");
    func("N3-41");
    func("N3-428");
}

int main()
{
    auto func = [](const char* s){ printf("%s\n",s); };

    GetInformation(func);
}
```